# how to check if an if statement inside of a for loop is never used?

Tags: java, android

i created a Method to check if users location are close to a building.

Therefore i created the following method

```
private void whereAreYou(final List<location> locations) {
    loadingprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < this.cities.size(); i++) {
        final location loc= locations.get(i);
        Location loc1 = mLastLocation;
        Location loc2 = new Location("");
        loc2.setLatitude(loc.getLat());
        loc2.setLongitude(loc.getLng());

        float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
        int distanceInKm = (int) (distanceInMeters / 1000);

        if (distanceInKm <= Integer.parseInt(currentclub.getRadius())) {
            uploadInformationToUserProfile(loc.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to check if a value was within the if statements or not, because then another method must be called, but only if all values ​​do not fit

Comment: So what are you looking for here?  Do you want us to give you code to cover the `if all values do not fit` requirement?  Something else?

Comment: yes exactly this is what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a flag that is set to false initially, and within the if statement action code set the flag to true.  Following that section of code print it to the console.

Then iterate through the appropriate test cases and check if it ever appears as true.

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean flag.

```
private void whereAreYou(final List<location> locations) {
    loadingprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    boolean locationMatchFound = false; //boolean flag

    for (int i = 0; i < this.cities.size(); i++) {
        final location loc= locations.get(i);
        Location loc1 = mLastLocation;
        Location loc2 = new Location("");
        loc2.setLatitude(loc.getLat());
        loc2.setLongitude(loc.getLng());

        float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
        int distanceInKm = (int) (distanceInMeters / 1000);
        if (distanceInKm <= Integer.parseInt(currentclub.getRadius())) {
            locationMatchFound = true; //boolean flag set to true if location found

            uploadInformationToUserProfile(loc.getName());
        }
    }
    if (!locationMatchFound){
        //Call your other method.
    }
}
```